# Why does TFunc<T> deference properly, but array [0..1] of TFunc<T> not?

Tags: delphi, generics

If I have a `TFunc<T: class>` a variable of that type will allow me to do dereference the class members directly.
Even class completion supports it.

[image]

If however I have an array of `TFunc<T>`'s then this does not compile.
**Why not? Is this a compiler error or is there some underlying reason?**

```
program Project33;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TTestObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface)
    procedure Test;
  end;

procedure TTestObject.Test;
begin
  WriteLn('Test');
end;

procedure Test;
var
  A: IInterface;
  TestObject: array [0..4] of TFunc<TTestObject>;
  SingleObject: TFunc<TTestObject>;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to 4 do begin
    a:= TTestObject.Create;
    TestObject[i]:= function: TTestObject
    begin
      Result:= a as TTestObject;
    end;
    TestObject[i].Test;   //<<-- does not compile
    SingleObject:= TestObject[i];
    SingleObject.Test;   // <<-- works.
  end;
end;

begin
  Test; ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: TestObject[i]().Test

Comment: This must be a quirk of the parser. But the basic problem is the language allowing you to omit the function call parens. That results in ambiguity. It seems that the parser is confused in this case when trying to resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: Very similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/q/26144675/327083  Not sure it's a duplicate... if not, @DavidHeffernan, your comment should probably be an answer.

Comment: @J... It's related to that thorny issue of omitting the parens when calling functions with no arguments. I've written an answer that includes some evidence that this is an oversight by the compiler devs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pascal allows the parens to be omitted when calling a function or procedure that has no parameters. In your code `SingleObject` is a function, and

```
SingleObject.Test
```

is equivalent to

```
SingleObject().Test
```

There is an ambiguity here. When the parser encounters `SingleObject`, it has to decide whether you mean to refer to the function, or to call it. The parser resolves that ambiguity by taking account of the context. In the example above, it decides that since you used the `.` operator, you must have intended for the function to be called, and then have the `.` operator applied to the value returned from that function call.

Now, for your array example, the parser appears to have trouble disambiguating. Personally I think that is an oversight. It is perfectly possible to disambiguate, so far as I can see.

Consider this program:

```
type
  TRec = class
    procedure Foo; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TFunc = function: TRec;
  TFuncOfObj = function: TRec of object;
  TRefFunc = reference to function: TRec;

var
  ScalarFunc: TFunc;
  ArrFunc: array [0..0] of TFunc;
  ScalarFuncOfObj: TFuncOfObj;
  ArrFuncOfObj: array [0..0] of TFuncOfObj;
  ScalarRefFunc: TRefFunc;
  ArrRefFunc: array [0..0] of TRefFunc;

begin
  ScalarFunc.Foo; // fine
  ArrFunc[0].Foo; // fine
  ScalarFuncOfObj.Foo; // fine
  ArrFuncOfObj[0].Foo; // fine
  ScalarRefFunc.Foo; // fine
  ArrRefFunc[0].Foo; // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Foo'
end.
```

As you can see, only the array of reference function suffers the problem. My suspicion is that the compiler developers missed whatever steps are needed to handle this disambiguation when they added support for reference function types.

The work around is easy enough. You need to explicitly disambiguate:

```
ArrRefFunc[0]().Foo;
```

This entire issue steps from the decision in Pascal to allow function call parens to be omitted when the function has no parameters. In my opinion, given the issues with ambiguity that arise with modern programming styles, it would be nice to go back in time and change that decision.