# How do I create a case insensitive list of string?

Tags: delphi, collections, delphi-xe2, spring4d

I'm trying to create a list of string that is case-insensitive.

The `CreateList` method let's me pass in some overloads:

- `TComparison<System.string>`
- `IComparer<System.string>`

I tried to use `TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` like this:

```
var
  List: IList<string>;
begin
  List := TCollections.CreateList<string>(TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
end;
```

But since this comparer doesn't implement any of the above classes / interfaces that doesn't compile; I get:

> E2250 There is no overloaded version of `TCollections.CreateList<System.string>` that can be called with these arguments

Is there an implementation of one of those available in the spring4d framework?

Comment: Tstringlist itself can be set to case-insensity.

Comment: Excatly why not just simply use aTStringList?

Comment: If you had quoted the compiler error then it would have helped

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think so - it says: `E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'TCollections.CreateList<System.string>' that can be called with these arguments`.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I think that would have led me to the answer. It's a common problem, the ambiguity caused by allowing parameterless function calls to omit `()`. Even so, it's always best to quote error messages verbatim.

Comment: Will do that next time.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt TStringList doesn't support the enhanced higher order functions that Spring4D does.

Comment: Also I wanted to construct the list from an existing `IEnumerable<string>` which is as simple as `AddRange`, for `TStringList` it would have been more work.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff `TStringList.AddStrings(IEnumerable<T>.ToArray)` would have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write the parentheses:

```
var
  List: IList<string>;
begin
  List := TCollections.CreateList<string>(TStringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase());
end;
```

Later compiler versions can figure it out without.

Answer (score 1):

After closer inspection of the type `TComparison`:

```
type
  TComparison<T> = reference to function(const Left, Right: T): Integer;
```

The answer turns out to be quite tivial:

```
var
  List: IList<string>;
begin
  List := TCollections.CreateList<string>(AnsiCompareText);
end;
```

Comment: That's a workaround, the correct answer is Stefan's, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157034/why-does-tfunct-deference-properly-but-array-0-1-of-tfunct-not and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144675/generics-not-resolving-method-types-correctly?lq=1

Comment: @Johan Why is it a workaround? What's wrong with passing a simple comparer function?

Comment: Because the issue is the missing (). Your solution works around that by passing an argument that does not require (). Without that understanding you'll not know why it fails.

Comment: My original issue was that I couldn't get a case insensitive list, this is a perfectly fine answer to that problem. I also like Stefans answer better which is why I made it the accepted one. I still think that this answer adds some value for future visitors of the question.